# Amount of match combinations of creating a 5 v 5 team from a pool

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

This question is inspired by the popular games: [Dota 2](http://www.dota2.com), [Heroes of the Storm](http://us.battle.net/heroes/en/) and [League of Legends](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/); where players have to create two teams of 5 from a pool of "Heroes" in each match.

How many different combinations of games can be formed?

#### Scenario

There is a pool of `X` unique items:

> AA, AB, AC, AD, AE...  ZZ (for 676)

If each item can only be chosen once, how many 5 v 5 combinations can be made?

The order in the groups of 5 does not mater thus the combinations of choosing 5 from the pool will be `XC5`.

But now we have 2 groups of 5, and they affect each other, as in

> A, B, C, D, E vs F, G, H, I, J

Is the same as:

> F, G, H, I, J vs A, B, C, D, E
> *(sides changing does not matter)*

Is the same as:

> B, A, C, D, E vs G, F, H, I, J
> *(order doesn't matter inside the groups)*

But, is NOT the same as:

> F, B, C, D, E vs A, G, H, I, J
> *(changing items outside the group: A and F does matter)*

Thus `XC10` is not the correct solution.

#### Question

How many combinations can be made from a pool of `X` when choosing two groups of 5?

Comment: Is blue side vs. red side relevant? (That only changes a factor of 2, but still).

Comment: @Ian No, i don't think so. Thanks, will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the side matters, then one side can choose 5 heroes from the entire pool. After that, the other then chooses 5 heroes from the remaining pool. So you get

$${N \choose 5} {N-5 \choose 5}.$$

If the side doesn't matter, then divide that by 2. (In League of Legends there is reason to believe it matters, because the most popular map Summoner's Rift is not symmetric between blue and red side.)

Comment: really that easy? wow! Thanks